# Why guided partitioning create a sda2 of 1 KB?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I am testing on VirtualBox the installation of Ubuntu server, so I chose guided partitioning: use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM. I then chose the whole volume group (10 GB) for guided partitioning.

Once the installation has finished, I noticed that the partition scheme is:

`sda`  of 10 GB 
`sda1` of 487 MB mounted on /boot 
`sda2` of   1 KB 
`sda5` of   9.5 of 9.5 GB

`sda5` then is divided in two logical volumes, one for `/root` and the other for `swap`.

[image]

I wonder: why the guided partitioning has created a `sda2` useless partition of 1 KB? 
 It was more logical to create `sda1` for `/boot` and `sda2` as lvm partition, as explained for instance at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM).

This happens with any option of Guided Partitioning, with or without encryption.

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 10.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start       End         Size        Type        File system     Flags
 1      1049kB      512MB       511MB       primary     ext2            boot
 2      513MB       10.7GB      10.2GB      extended
 5      513MB       10.7GB      10.2GB      logical                     lvm
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print`?

Comment: Added to the original message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you got to the conclusion that `/dev/sda2` is only 1 kB large, but the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print` clearly shows the truth:

```
Number  Start       End         Size        Type        File system     Flags
 1      1049kB      512MB       511MB       primary     ext2            boot
 2      513MB       10.7GB      10.2GB      extended
 5      513MB       10.7GB      10.2GB      logical                     lvm
```

The primary partition `/dev/sda1` has a size of around 500 MB, which seems to be your boot partition.

`/dev/sda2` is an extended partition, which means it does not hold any data itself but just serves as a container for logical volumes, like `/dev/sda5`. Both the container and its contained volumes are around 10 GB in size.

Maybe the 1 kB you mentioned is the remaining unallocated space inside the extended partition `/dev/sda2` that is not taken by the `/dev/sda5` volume?

Comment: I used `lsblk`, and according to it sda2 is a partition of 1K size

Comment: I updated the original message with the output of `lsblk`

Comment: It is an extended partition as described by Byte Commander, and `lsblk` is displaying confusing information. This happens sometimes (not always) for me too (in Xenial alias 16.04 LTS).

Comment: Obviously `lsblk` is not able to deal with extended partitions correctly.

Comment: `fdisk -l` shows that sda2 starts at 1001470, while sda5 starts at 1001472. So probably it is as supposed by Byte Commander: there is unallocated space. That seems strange, so little unallocated space.

Comment: Partition borders are normally aligned to sector boundaries or whole MBs. That's why sometimes there are small unallocated areas between partitions, usually around 1 MB in size. Not sure how exactly it is with extended partitions though, could have a different reason here.